# Как вызвать OnPointerUp джойстика при определенном действии?

Tags: unity3d

Когда произвожу определенное действие, нужно чтобы джойстик отпускался сам, а не игроком. В коде думаю все будет понятно...) Как решить проблему?

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FloatingJoystick : Joystick
{
    public static bool isRunning;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isRunning == false)
        {
            background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            base.OnPointerUp(eventData); // ошибка "Имя не существует в текущем контексте"
        }
    }

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isRunning = true;

        background.anchoredPosition = ScreenPointToAnchoredPosition(eventData.position);
        background.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
    }
    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isRunning = false;

        background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Где ошибка то? Здесь: `base.OnPointerUp(eventData);`? Тебе же написали - имя не существует в текущем контексте. У тебя нет ничего с именем `eventData`. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я знаю что нет ничего с этим именем, в том то и проблема, что не знаю как можно добавить что-нибудь чтобы ошибка пропала

Comment: Тебе этот eventData и не нужен выдели в отдельный метод то, что происходит в OnPointerUp и вызывай этот метод, а не OnPointerUp.

Comment: private void Update()
    {
        if (isRunning == false)
        {
            JoystickUp();
        }
    }

    public void JoystickUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        background.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
    }

Comment: пробовал так, тоже не получается, ошибка при вызове JoystickUp

Comment: Конечно не получается, ты то же самое делаешь. Что ты вообще закостылить пытаешься? Что за класс Joystick, от которого ты наследуешься?

Comment: Джойстик с бесплатных ассетов

Comment: Закостылить хочу следущее: игрок держит палец на экране, джойстик работает, мне нужно сделать так: происходит определенное действие, джойстик отпускался сам, даже если игрок продолжает держать палец на экране

Comment: Зачем ты вообще вызываешь base.OnPointerUp в апдейте? Нужен ли он там тебе? Что он делает?

Comment: OnPointerUp делает то, что я описал, но не хватает знаний чтобы это реализовать

Comment: Ты используешь где-то базовый Joystick или будешь использовать? Не проще ли туда все эти изменения внести, чтобы не делать то, что ты делаешь? Этот класс, по всей видимости, невозможно нормально расширить. Скопируй [сюда](https://hatebin.com/) код Joystick и скинь мне ссылку.

Comment: Я разобрался, в скрипте Joystick сделал почти то же самое, что пытался до этого. Спасибо, что направил в нужное русло)